# Wordpress permalink from the database?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to access selected post information from my WordPress database to display on a second website which is not a WordPress site nor is it php, it is in fact an asp.net website that i want to display the information on.

I have a WordPress blog at blog.domain.com and another website at domain.com both running on different servers and I need to display the excerpt, title with link on my asp.net website for selected posts. I can easily grab the excerpt and title from the blog's database but the only problem is that the permalink is not in the database.

I had the idea that maybe if I place a short piece of code on every blog to insert the permalink to a new table, i could then grab that to use over on the other website. But that didnt work, perhaps I am not doing it right. This is the code I used;

```
<?php
 global $wpdb;
 $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "posts_pages_url";
 $wpdb->insert($table_name , array('post_id' => the_ID(), 'url' => the_permalink()));
?>
```

Some might say, "why dont you just use an RSS Feed?" Well if it comes down to it, I just might have to, but i would prefer not to as connecting to the database directly to access my selected posts is much more flexible.

I would be very grateful if anyone had any suggestions on how I can access the permalink via a database call.

Many thanks

Comment: Consider asking on [wordpress.se].

Comment: I put this code in the php file for the webpage I was testing.

Comment: There are many PHP files in a Wordpress installation, which file did you place the code in? If you placed it in template, did you place it inside the Wordpress loop?

Comment: Yes the template file for the page I was testing. Yes the code was placed within the loop.

Comment: the_permalink() will display the permalink so isn't suitable for saving it to the database. Use get_permalink instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [get_permalink()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) in your code, or link to the guid value in the DB - not ideal I know, but it should at least work.

EDIT:

Same goes for [the_ID()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID) - it should be changed to [get_the_ID()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID).

Comment: Thanks @Mark, I changed the code now to


`<?php
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "posts_pages_url";
$wpdb->insert($table_name , array('post_id' => get_the_ID(), 'url' => get_permalink()));
?>`

But still the data is not being entered into the database. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @robolist, sorry for the delay in response. I have tested that code on a sample WP install at it works for me. Without wanting to be patronising, is the wp_posts_pages_url table set up in the DB with appropriate datatypes? (Swapping wp_ with whatever your prefix is if it isn't the default).

Comment: If that doesn't work, let me know where you're putting that code - I put it on the individual posts/pages files - so single.php and page.php in the theme.

Answer (score 0):

This code will get it for you if using Yoast

```
            $q = "SELECT * FROM wp_yoast_indexable yi 
                    WHERE object_type = 'post'
                    AND object_id = '$ref'";
    
            $yis =  $scDb->select($q);
            
            $permaLink = "";
            
            if(isset($yis[0]))
            {
                $permaLink = $yis[0]->permalink;
            }
```